# bootstrap not applied at some point

Tags: jquery, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have one page where I am using bootstrap.
When I resize my window then at certain point bootsrtap is not getting applied.
Bellow are screen shots of my page 
Full length:
[image]

After I resize:
[image]

I am using bootstrap v2.3.2
I am enable to fix this problem. Can any one help in this ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got a 'gap' in your media queries for your inputs (with css `span10`:

There's one for `media (max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 768px)` and there's one for `@media (min-width: 1200px)`. So you're missing a media-query for [980,1199]

Current media queries:

```
  media (max-width: 979px) and (min-width: 768px)
 .row-fluid .span10 {
    width: 82.90598290598291%;
  }

  @media (min-width: 1200px)
  .row-fluid .span10 {
     width: 82.87292817679558%;
  }
```

P.s.: launch Chrome inspector (F12 in Google Chrome) and get acquainted with it to quickly see for yourself.

Comment: Yes you are right but I downloaded this css file from bootstrap only.

Answer (score 0):

For some reason, your bootstrap.min.css doesn't contain Bootstrap's default grid CSS, and so when the browser window is within that width, it doesn't have any styles to apply to your .span* classes.

If you copy and paste the following in to bootstrap.min.css (and include that css file before bootstrap-responsive.css) then it should work.

http://pastebin.com/LC50YSGn